# Inserting Record into SQL Server using Xamarin

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, xamarin, xamarin.android

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"server=MOON\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Moon;Integrated Security=True");

protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

        // Get our button from the layout resource,
        // and attach an event to it
        Button button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnsubmit);

        button.Click += button_Click;
}

void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        try
        {
            EditText etuser = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.txtuser);
            EditText etpass = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.txtpass);
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into Login values('" + etuser.Text + "','" + etpass.Text + "')", con);
            cmd.ExecuteReader();
            con.Close();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            string result;
            result = ex.Message;
            Toast.MakeText(this, result, ToastLength.Short).Show();
        }
}
```

Please help me out I want to insert a record but an error shows up

> Could not resolve host `MOON`

Please help me out. I am using local database and my server name is also `MOON\SQLExpress`.

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Comment: You need to specify an IP or fully qualified domain name for your server.  Also note that connecting directly to a db server from your mobile app is a horrible idea.  You should generally use a webservices layer to do that instead.

Comment: It's not a good idea to connect to your database directly from your mobile app. Create some basic web API which will offer desired functionality. Or use some cloud API for mobile applications. Unless you are working on a sql management studio for mobile.

Comment: Thanks alot for your help

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a (selfhosted) webservice on your sqlserver computer.
2. Run your service as admin
3. Create a service consuming class with  SlSvcUtil

(Download & Install from:  https://www.microsoft.com/de-DE/download/details.aspx?id=28359)

3. Put this class in your xamarin project
4. consume the service in your app